# Selenium can't find divs when deploying in Heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku

I am trying to grab the 2 tables from this link: https://www.nba.com/standings?GroupBy=conf&Season=2019-20&Section=overall

I can grab them like this when my app is not deployed to Heroku

```
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.nba.com/standings?GroupBy=conf&Season=2019-20&Section=overall'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.select('div.StandingsGridRender_standingsContainer__2EwPy')
```

but when I deploy my app to Heroku, I have to specify the chromedriver and this is what my code looks like:

```
url = 'https://www.nba.com/standings?GroupBy=conf&Season=2019-20&Section=overall'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver"

chrome_bin = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN', "chromedriver")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = chrome_bin
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.select('div.StandingsGridRender_standingsContainer__2EwPy')
```

Whenever I run this code on Heroku I get an IndexError saying that the list index is out of range (I pull the tables from tables[0] and tables[1] later on in my code)

Is there a way I can figure out why the tables are not getting grabbed? Is there a pop up that is keeping the driver from accessing the tables? I tried to specify --disable-popup-blocking but have had no luck. Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to tell what's going on from looking at the code. Your best bet would be to inspect the page source and work your way from there. As a stab in the dark... Maybe your window size is so small that it ends up changing the format of the page. Maybe there's something blocking requests from heroku (e.g. cloudflare or similar solution) -- Hard to say without seeing what the browser is seeing.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to scrape the table then why are you using bs4?

You can use only selenium and use"find_element_by_xpath", "find_element_by_tage_name", "find_element_by_class_name"...etc

when you got the value then use ".text" to extract the text.